Will a laptop battery that stays connected to its charger be damaged?
I have a laptop that stays connected to the charger most of the time and only occasionally uses battery.
Is this bad for the battery? Is there a possibility to be damaged?

the battery charger is inside to laptop ... the external device is a power supply,  not a charger

Most modern laptops have a choice of "charge fully, as I will be traveling" and on the other hand "I am sitting at a desk so only charge moderately".

Older laptops will not have the regulating circuitry and operating system support to reduce the state of charge maximum. This means that those older laptops will eventually cause battery failure, typically three to five years of use.
A recent Dell laptop purchase presented me with a message suggesting that I limit the charge to 80% automatically by selecting that option. I experienced a similar feature with a laptop of a different manufacturer.
For an older laptop, if you can manage such a schedule, operate your laptop on battery alone to about 50% discharge and then recharge to about 80%, perhaps on a monthly basis. It would not be harmful to perform this more frequently, but less often could result in deterioration of the battery life.
This 80% reference is common in many of today's battery operated systems. It's suggested that electric vehicles also charge to that level, unless full range is required.

I'm wondering how old older is, and how likely it is that such laptops are still in use? My lenovo from 2013 has this feature.

So you voluntarily only use 30% of the battery capacity, constantly recharging. Effectively, you suffer all the disadvantages from a degraded battery already! ;-)

@Haukinger My laptop is of year 2022. Asus

@Peter-ReinstateMonica On my laptop, I use two settings. A setcharge setting with a very conservative 40%-60% SoC window while the device is connected to the mains (charging stops at 60 % and, while still connected to the mains, the battery will discharge only very slowly over many days), and a fullcharge setting with a 96%-100% (effectively "always charging when connected") setting for travel. The idea is not to use the latter setting permanently, but only when needed, and leave the battery at a "cozy" SoC when not needed.

@AlexanderKlauer That makes sense. With removable batteries, there were people who would use the lappie on power all the time, without battery (even though that was not always an officially sanctioned MO); the battery would be in the fridge, 80% charged.

All modern laptops handle the issue for you.

Windows laptops. All modern ones I have seen have a choice of two settings.  "Fill completely because I will be travelling", or choose, "I am at my desk and connected mode, don't fill completely."

Apple have some AI to do the selection for you to some extent, or, you can turn it off and charge the hell out of it.


Indeed, the relevant Apple option box does an excellent job of explaining everything the OP is asking:

In answer to the OP's two literal questions,

Is this bad for the battery?

In the abstract, yes. But note that
(1) Literally everything is bad for batteries. All batteries wear out. (Note that the battery in my all-but-new laptop, from the screenshot, is already 9% messed up!
(2) 100% of modern laptops totally manage this for you. Do nothing. Leave it plugged in always and completely forget about the issue.

Is there a possibility to be damaged?

With all modern laptops, no chance.

For completeness, if the "AI" on your MacBook doesn't do a good enough job of detecting your usage patterns and limiting your battery charge when not needed, there are third-party apps that provide more Windows-like direct control of battery charging on Mac too. AlDente is one I've personally used for a while, with a decent experience so far.

right - lol funny app name and apposite :)

When your laptop is connected to the Alternating Current (AC) adapter it not using the battery - the laptop will power directly from the electrical network. This will increase your battery lifespan.
Modern laptops batteries have built-in controller that is controlling the rechanging process. The controller does not allow the battery to charge more than necessary and doesn't allow it to discharge completely.
Therefore, you don't need to care about the battery damage.
UPDATE:
If you want to see your laptop battery health run the powercfg /batteryreport and check the report. More detailed information is here: How to Generate Battery Report Using the POWERCFG Command
Description from the article:

If the "Full Charge Capacity" is less than 25% of the Designed
Capacity and the battery is more than a year old, this is normal. If
the battery is less than a year old, the battery may need to be
replaced. The System BIOS can be checked as well for the battery
health.

About the increasing the Charging Cycles.
In my opinion this information cannot be used to determine the battery life. The lithium-ion batteries from many manufacturers can stand about 1,000 charge cycles (HP, MacBook).

Ok , but i run periodically powercfg/batteryreport , and the Charging Cycles are incerasing . So it seems that battery is charging. My laptop is of year 2022.

@DonikaDonika: See my update in the answer above.

I'm curious where you get that 2000 charging cycles number from. Lenovo says laptop batteries generally last "300-500 charge cycles". I haven't seen any datasheets for lithium-ion batteries with more than 500 cycles.. Supposedly Apple's will last 1000 cycles, but I couldn't find a reliable source for that. LiFePo4, NMC, and Sodium-Ion do have 1k> cycle lifes, but only a couple laptops appear to use LiFePo4.

@MagnieMozios: Thanks for remark. HP and MacBook can have for 1K charge circles. Seems last long batteries for laptops, like Lithium-Titanate, that can have >2k charge cycles only on research stage.

Just to add a data point: I'm writing this on a Macbook that is 2 years old, is being used every day (while plugged in), the system report shows 184 cycles, and the battery has lost a mere 6% of its designed capacity. So yeah, the controller seems to be doing its job remarkably well.
